# I can no longer review tag edits, but I still get notifications

Tags: support

Up until recently, I would get a little flag with a number when there were tag edits suggested. I would click on the flag, and I could approve or reject the edits. Now, I still get the flag, but no longer can edit. This is a little annoying.

Has anyone had this problem? Did you resolve it?

Comment: Is the button still there?  is it greyed out?  do you get an error when you click it?

Comment: @SamIam I think I may have figured out the issue, but someone has already cleared the tag edits (maybe you :-)) so I'll have to wait until someone else makes a tag edit.

Comment: Ok, so it started again. Here's what I see. Starting from my icon moving to the right, I see my icon, my reputation, my badges, an orange box with the number of tags to review, the word 'review', the word 'help' with a down-triangle, and the search box. When I click on the little box, I get redirected to the review queue, but there are no edits. The box is still visible.

Comment: by "the little box" do you mean that orange box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what you're talking about.

When I go through the review queues, the number of notifications in the top bar is sometimes higher than the number of items to actually review.

What I believe happens, is that when you click "skip" on an item in the queue, it doesn't show up in the queue again for you, but it does not subtract from that number.